# Is writing and publishing a summary narrative of someone else's electronic game story an infringement of copyright?

Tags: copyright

Our son has watched every episode of UnderTale (which is a video game) and written a narrative describing each episode.  He's not a kid who has a lot of self-confidence (he's on the spectrum which may, in part, explain his focus on this project) and I think it would be a real boost to his self-confidence if we published this on Amazon.

However, is this a copyright infringement, so long as we identify what it is (just a set of narratives) and cite the creator, Toby Fox?

Comment: A good benchmark for how much of a summary can be non-infringing is to look a Wikipedia entries on particular TV shows, movies, video games, books and plays. A synopsis is usually acceptable, an exhaustive narrative account without permission and without much literary or critical analysis would ordinarily be an infringing derivative work. There is no hard and fast rule to distinguish what crosses the line and many narrative descriptions are in a gray area.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not qualified to answer the question regarding copyright, but consider that Toby Fox may find your son's efforts to be a positive thing, effectively presenting a review of the game.

According to the [Wikipedia page, Toby Fox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undertale) is an independent game creator and an independent individual, having created the game on his own, along with the music.

I would suggest to contact Toby Fox and ask his permission for your son's project. The results of a positive response would certainly settle the copyright issue, although my personal belief is that a review is not subject to copyright. A narrative in your son's own words, not a review, is akin to a book-report (is that still a thing today?) and also may not be infringement.

It appears that Toby's web site has a [contact email](https://undertale.com/help/) on the FAQ page. The page suggests to read the FAQ before sending an email, but none of the topics cover your situation.